# Working with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-routes

Imagine this. I'm on the URL `http://localhost:3000/companies/3`, and on this view, I want an `employees` button that takes me to `http://localhost:3000/companies/3/employees`

In my routes file, I have

```
  namespace :companies, :only => [:index, :show, :new, :edit, :destroy], :path => "/:companies" do
    resources :employees, :only => [:index, :edit, :new, :show] do
    end
  end
```

I understand that I need to link to the index action of 'employees', but I don't know what to add to my companies 'show' page. Right now, it looks like

```
%a{title: "company1", href: "#"} Employees
```

(I am using haml, but feel free to post your answer in erb)

In rake routes, I get

```
companies_employees GET    /:companies/employees(.:format)          companies/employees#index
```

... but I want companies/company_id/employees

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**link to employees in the company show page**

```
<%= link_to 'Employees', company_employees_path(@company) %>
```

**employees controller**

```
def index
  @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
  @employees = @company.employees
end
```

**routes**

```
  resources :companies do
    resources :employees
  end
```

**rake routes**

`company_employees GET        /companies/:company_id/employees(.:format)                                employees#index`